# Cannot parse data into cosmos db via parallel tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently having issues with seeding my cosmos db parallel tasks.

Having a simple foreach where I create one item at a time is not an issue, but when I create them in parallel I seem to run into problems`?

I mainly run into two issues,
Either that the `CreateItemAsync()` method fails due to a request timeout

```
[2022-07-25T22:11:40.300Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '2a65e92a-443c-4574-a226-2e6c01cb8cbd'.
[2022-07-25T22:11:40.305Z] Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: Response status code does not indicate success: RequestTimeout (408); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ; Reason: ();; Diagnostics:{"name":"CreateItemAsync","id":"12121d39-9b1b-417d-b4a4-0b0a4bf7c05c","caller info":{"member":"OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync","file":"ClientContextCore.cs","line":244},"start time":"10:07:23:341","duration in milliseconds":11111.2478,"data":{"Client Configuration":{"Client Created Time Utc":"2022-07-25T22:03:50.1943660Z","NumberOfClientsCreated":1,"User Agent":"cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.21.0|3.21.1|1|X64|Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044|.NET 6.0.6|N| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/6.0.7","ConnectionConfig":{"gw":"(cps:50, urto:10, p:False, httpf: False)","rntbd":"(cto: 5, icto: -1, mrpc: 30, mcpe: 65535, erd: True, pr: ReuseUnicastPort)","other":"(ed:False, be:False)"},"ConsistencyConfig":"(consistency: NotSet, prgns:[])"}},"children":[{"name":"ItemSerialize","id":"11244b99-0a45-49bc-a2e6-9808979f7eff","caller info":{"member":"ExtractPartitionKeyAndProcessItemStreamAsync","file":"ContainerCore.Items.cs","line":941},"start time":"10:07:23:341","duration in milliseconds":12.6545},{"name":"Get PkValue From Stream","id":"abae0c82-4f3a-4276-bc23-050f9cc7d402","caller info":{"member":"GetPartitionKeyValueFromStreamAsync","file":"ContainerCore.Items.cs","line":1047},"start time":"10:07:23:353","duration in milliseconds":14.5511,"children":[{"name":"Get Collection Cache","id":"3eb837d1-24c4-451e-aa2d-f3e4e81c11e1","caller info":{"member":"GetCollectionCacheAsync","file":"DocumentClient.cs","line":546},"start time":"10:07:23:355","duration in milliseconds":0.0045}]},{"name":"Get Collection Cache","id":"6c4ff202-47c3-4feb-ae6f-b5325ac424c1","caller info":{"member":"GetCollectionCacheAsync","file":"DocumentClient.cs","line":546},"start time":"10:07:23:368","duration in milliseconds":0.0028},{"name":"Batch Dispatch Async","id":"efdfe740-a9fa-44b8-915d-85bb47860aaa","caller info":{"member":"DispatchAsync","file":"BatchAsyncBatcher.cs","line":116},"start time":"10:07:23:441","duration in milliseconds":10988.2685,"children":[{"name":"Using Wait","id":"963ad1a0-e77b-4d2a-8452-c5fb82fa10b4","caller info":{"member":"UsingWaitAsync","file":"Extensions.cs","line":189},"start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":0.0066},{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler","id":"3af70bd2-a4a1-441b-9bb9-56ecffe29884","start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10976.7615,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.DiagnosticsHandler","id":"3a400763-8df7-4b70-ae85-a0f1b65cb900","start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10976.7191,"data":{"System Info":{"systemHistory":[{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:06:27.3932981Z","cpu":48,280,"memory":661624,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0,4477,"availableThreads":32757,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:06:45.3806533Z","cpu":46,781,"memory":372680,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0,5471,"availableThreads":32752,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:06:56.4321174Z","cpu":53,737,"memory":546504,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0,9583,"availableThreads":32757,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:07:13.2966590Z","cpu":45,395,"memory":781392,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":1,5006,"availableThreads":32747,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:07:23.3328524Z","cpu":39,992,"memory":568480,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0,0167,"availableThreads":32764,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}},{"dateUtc":"2022-07-25T22:07:33.7334358Z","cpu":36,768,"memory":2166908,000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0,3091,"availableThreads":32754,"minThreads":8,"maxThreads":32767}}]}},"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RetryHandler","id":"5ac8d97a-e29b-401b-97d1-d76e11caa8f0","start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10976.7031,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RouterHandler","id":"58123336-42cf-4296-9d1f-a2ee6e44ff99","start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10969.5043,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler","id":"9d0490cd-5462-4411-b0e4-647af78a8571","start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10969.5008,"children":[{"name":"Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServerStoreModel Transport Request","id":"2d54108b-ccaf-478e-892b-4ae6cda1ffd8","caller info":{"member":"ProcessMessageAsync","file":"TransportHandler.cs","line":109},"start time":"10:07:23:448","duration in milliseconds":10925.5148,"data":{"Client Side Request Stats":{"Id":"AggregatedClientSideRequestStatistics","ContactedReplicas":[{"Count":1,"Uri":"rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd31.documents.azure.com:14099/apps/e585d347-b00f-4297-95a7-bf892b6af7ee/services/b83080cb-d31c-42a1-a972-0aaa16edbe6a/partitions/1bb1b4cc-7abd-4f62-9b76-96ef3a88202b/replicas/133032591643382240s/"},{"Count":1,"Uri":"rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd31.documents.azure.com:14128/apps/e585d347-b00f-4297-95a7-bf892b6af7ee/services/b83080cb-d31c-42a1-a972-0aaa16edbe6a/partitions/1bb1b4cc-7abd-4f62-9b76-96ef3a88202b/replicas/133032591643382238s/"},{"Count":1,"Uri":"rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd31.documents.azure.com:14486/apps/e585d347-b00f-4297-95a7-bf892b6af7ee/services/b83080cb-d31c-42a1-a972-0aaa16edbe6a/partitions/1bb1b4cc-7abd-4f62-9b76-96ef3a88202b/replicas/133032591643382239s/"}],"RegionsContacted":[],"FailedReplicas":[],"AddressResolutionStatistics":[],"StoreResponseStatistics":[]},"Point Operation Statistics":{"Id":"PointOperationStatistics","ActivityId":"72b93711-f63e-472d-bca5-dc6db75c512b","ResponseTimeUtc":"2022-07-25T22:07:34.4175901Z","StatusCode":408,"SubStatusCode":0,"RequestCharge":0,"RequestUri":"dbs/hubspot/colls/hubspot_forms","ErrorMessage":"Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException: Message: Request timed out. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-request-timeout\r\nActivityId: 72b93711-f63e-472d-bca5-dc6db75c512b, Request URI: /apps/e585d347-b00f-4297-95a7-bf892b6af7ee/services/b83080cb-d31c-42a1-a972-0aaa16edbe6a/partitions/1bb1b4cc-7abd-4f62-9b76-96ef3a88202b/replicas/133032591045575942p/, RequestStats: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum, SDK: Windows/10.0.19044 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.21.1\r\n ---> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportException: A client transport error occurred: The request timed out while waiting for a server response. (Time: 2022-07-25T22:07:33.7660617Z, activity ID: 72b93711-f63e-472d-bca5-dc6db75c512b, error code: ReceiveTimeout [0x0010], base error: HRESULT 0x80131500, URI: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd31.documents.azure.com:14131/apps/e585d347-b00f-4297-95a7-bf892b6af7ee/services/b83080cb-d31c-42a1-a972-0aaa16edbe6a/partitions/1bb1b4cc-7abd-4f62-9b76-96ef3a88202b/replicas/133032591045575942p/, connection: 192.168.68.107:58301 -> 13.69.66.133:14131, payload sent: True)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.Channel.RequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, ResourceOperation resourceOperation, Guid activityId, TransportRequestStats transportRequestStats)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.LoadBalancingPartition.RequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, ResourceOperation resourceOperation, Guid activityId, TransportRequestStats transportRequestStats)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.TransportClient.InvokeStoreAsync(TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, ResourceOperation resourceOperation, DocumentServiceRequest request)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.TransportClient.InvokeStoreAsync(TransportAddressUri physicalAddress, ResourceOperation resourceOperation, DocumentServiceRequest request)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyWriter.WritePrivateAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, TimeoutHelper timeout, Boolean forceRefresh)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreResult.VerifyCanContinueOnException(DocumentClientException ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreResult.CreateStoreResult(StoreResponse storeResponse, Exception responseException, Boolean requiresValidLsn, Boolean useLocalLSNBasedHeaders, Uri storePhysicalAddress)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyWriter.WritePrivateAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, TimeoutHelper timeout, Boolean forceRefresh)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyWriter.WriteAsync(DocumentServiceRequest entity, TimeoutHelper timeout, Boolean forceRefresh, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestRetryUtility.ProcessRequestAsync[TRequest,IRetriableResponse](Func`1 executeAsync, Func`1 prepareRequest, IRequestRetryPolicy`2 policy, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, Nullable`1 minBackoffForInBackoffCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestRetryUtility.ProcessRequestAsync[TRequest,IRetriableResponse](Func`1 executeAsync, Func`1 prepareRequest, IRequestRetryPolicy`2 policy, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, Nullable`1 minBackoffForInBackoffCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreClient.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IRetryPolicy retryPolicy, Func`2 prepareRequestAsyncDelegate)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.ProcessMessageAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)","RequestSessionToken":null,"ResponseSessionToken":null,"BELatencyInMs":null}}}]}]}]}]}]},{"name":"Create Trace","id":"fa07e0e9-b014-4326-a421-4c695f46b5a5","caller info":{"member":"FromResponseMessageAsync","file":"TransactionalBatchResponse.cs","line":214},"start time":"10:07:34:425","duration in milliseconds":0.2022}]},{"name":"Get Collection Cache","id":"93c17029-8317-4c8d-b6d5-049a24b337d6","caller info":{"member":"GetCollectionCacheAsync","file":"DocumentClient.cs","line":546},"start time":"10:07:34:429","duration in milliseconds":0.0039}]}.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Press any key to continue....1338
[2022-07-25T22:11:55.655Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-07-26T00:11:55.5079325+02:00', Id=87de5f5c-324b-489b-a34d-b70e8bfd3c4a)
[2022-07-25T22:11:55.661Z] Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2022-07-25T23:47:00.0000000+02:00
```

Or cancelled due to a null value? which I am not quite sure about

```
[2022-07-25T23:45:25.883Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '3d240368-6ccb-4d79-8ec9-613407642f32'.
[2022-07-25T23:45:25.885Z] A task was canceled.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

startup.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using hubspot_form_retriever.DatabaseContext;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(hubspot_form_retriever.Startup))]
namespace hubspot_form_retriever
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<HubspotModelContext>();
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            using var context = new HubspotModelContext();
            SeedingTools.SeedDataAsync(context).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

seedingtools.cs

```
using hubspot_form_retriever.DatabaseContext;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hubspot_form_retriever
{
    internal class SeedingTools
    {
        public static async Task SeedDataAsync(HubspotModelContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var cosmosClient = context.Database.GetCosmosClient();
            //Efcore count does not work, and there is no other way of counting this. 
            cosmosClient.ClientOptions.AllowBulkExecution = true;
            cosmosClient.ClientOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            var count = CosmosQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(context.Forms, $"SELECT * FROM c").Count();
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                using var client = new HttpClient();
                var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer("hubspot", "hubspot_forms");
                await InsertFormsToDb(container, client).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private static async Task InsertFormsToDb(Container container, HttpClient client)
        {
            List <int> tasks = new();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            int totalCount = await GetNumberOfFormsAvailableAsync(client);
            for (int offset = 0; offset <= totalCount; offset += 100)
            { 
                tasks.Add(offset);
            }

            IEnumerable<Task> a = tasks.Select(async offSet => await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Started Inserting Forms of offset {offSet} time {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
                HubspotModel[] forms = await GetFormsAsync(client, 100, offSet);
                foreach (var form in forms)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Currently on offSet {offSet} Form {form.Id} time {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
                    var itemsResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync(form);
                    if (itemsResponse.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"OffSet {offSet} failed Exception {itemsResponse}.");
                    }

                    if (itemsResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000);
                        try
                        {
                            await container.CreateItemAsync(form);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Inserted Forms of offset {offSet} time {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
            }));

            //for (int offset = 0; offset <= totalCount; offset += 100)
            //{
            //    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            //    {
            //        HubspotModel[] forms = await GetFormsAsync(client, 100, offset);
            //        foreach (HubspotModel form in forms)
            //        {
            //            var itemsResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync(form);
            //            if (itemsResponse.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            //            {
            //                Console.WriteLine($"OffSet {offset} failed Exception {itemsResponse}.");
            //            }
            //        }
            //        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted Forms {offset} time {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
            //    }));

            //}
            await Task.WhenAll(a);
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }

        private static async Task<HubspotModel[]> GetFormsAsync(HttpClient client, int pageSize, int offset)
        {
            string url = $"https://api.hubapi.com/forms/v2/forms?hapikey=" +
                $"{HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={pageSize}&offset={offset}";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>(content);

            Guid guid = Guid.Parse(jsonResponse.First()["guid"].ToString());
            HubspotModel[] forms = jsonResponse.Select(x => new HubspotModel()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse(x["guid"].ToString()),
                FormName = x["name"].ToString(),
                Form = x,
                lastUpdated = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse(x["updatedAt"].ToString()))
            }).ToArray();
            return forms;
        }

        private static async Task<int> GetNumberOfFormsAvailableAsync(HttpClient client)
        {
            string url = $"https://api.hubapi.com/forms/v2/forms?hapikey={HubspotConfiguration.ApiKey}&limit={1}&offset={0}";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            int totalCount = int.Parse(response.Headers.GetValues("x-total-count").First());
            return totalCount;
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried to capture all items response, such that I could handle the exceptions as they come, but for some reason am I not able to capture these two, and probably more?

What am I doing wrong?

I seem to be following the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/tutorial-sql-api-dotnet-bulk-import) put out by microsoft, so I cannot see where I going wrong here?

Beside, any optimization I can do to speed up the seeding?

Comment: Are you timing out after 30 seconds?  Error indicates you did not get a response back from server.  You are using HTTP where there is a request and a response.  Looks like the response is null.  The only way response can be null is if nothing was returned.  Normally default timeout is 30 seconds.

Comment: i have set it to 30 sec,  I don't whether I run into some issues with the number of threads I am running, but that only 20?

SO i am bit confused on what is going wrong here? @jdweng...

Comment: I am not capturing the error due to missing try-catch. an exeption but nothing in this seem to indicate an error?

Comment: I don't think the server is accepting multiple connections from client.  So you are getting a timeout when connection fails.

Answer (score 1):

At least on the write error, the timeouts are Write Timeouts:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportException: A client transport error occurred: The request timed out while waiting for a server response.
```

The SDK cannot retry write timeouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#timeouts-and-connectivity-related-failures-http-408503

You need to decide what to do with them and how to retry them. If you do retry them, understand that it can either succeed or fail with a Conflict (if the previous timeout actually reached the service).

Timeouts can happen due to multiple reasons, the [aka.ms link](https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-request-timeout) has more details. Make sure the Function instance size is good enough to process the volume of operations, check the Function health (CPU and SNAT metrics).

Comment: I have via polly added handling for status code 429 and 5xx, but 408 seems a bit troublesome, as you mention yourself I can either be there or not.

Comment: A dffernet way of solvinf this was to use upsert instead of instead if insert.